# add html tag to table using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to show br tag `<br>` inside a table dynamically added using jquery.

Html:

```
<table id="TempTable"></table>
```

Javascript:

```
var _textFromDatabase = "Hello,<br><br><br><br> How are you?";
var _trText = "<tr><td>" + $('<div/>').html(_textFromDatabase).text() + "</td></tr>";
$("#TempTable").html("<code>"+ _trText + "</code>");
```

I need to show `Hello,<br><br><br><br> How are you?` inside the table dynamically. But with the above code it replaces the br tag and adds as new line to the page. How can we show the html tag as such in the database in the page? In MVC, we can achieve it using Html.Raw, but the above code with jquery is not working. Please suggest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/ghqyL/)**

```
var _textFromDatabase = "Hello,<br><br><br><br> How are you?";
var _trText = "<tr><td>" + $('<div/>').text(_textFromDatabase).text().replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;') + "</td></tr>";
$("#TempTable").html("<code>"+ _trText + "</code>");
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this instead :

```
$("#TempTable").append('<tr>').
                append('<td>').
                text(_textFromDatabase.replace('<br','&lt;br'));
```

[image]

Comment: I need to show the br in the page. i.e. whatever text i have in my database.  From the Image u added, it replaced the br with new line. It shouldn't

Comment: Sorry, thought the opposit - instead of deleting here a little update, but not perfect though - still misses the first `<br>`

Answer (score 0):

```
var _textFromDatabase = "Hello,&lt;br&mt;&lt;br&mt;&lt;br&mt;br&lt; How are you?";
```

By making sure the string is encoded correctly you will be able to render it correctly. This will also provide extra security towards javascript and html defacement attacks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of writing this :

```
   var _textFromDatabase = "Hello,<br><br><br><br> How are you?";
```

Try this one :

```
   var _textFromDatabase = "Hello, &lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br&gt; How are you?";
```

Hope that you will get solution for your problem.